# How to get around WP REST API per page limit without pagination?

Tags: rest-api

So I know that using `/wp-json/wp/v2/customposts/?per_page=100&page=2` will allow me to bypass the default of 10 returned at a time. But I am trying to return over 2k custom posts. The only other way I have seen to return all is to modify the per page maximum in the plugin, which I'd prefer not to do.

Does anyone know another way to return all content without pagination?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/